# chinese <-> english database of translations / character meanings

Tags: unicode, translation

I'm planing on developing a webapp that will use a novel way to help people to learn chinese characters and remember their meaning.

Since I don't want/can't spend years translating all chinese characters by hand I wonder wether there is a (favorably open source) database (of any form) providing this, i.e. chinese character <-> english translation.

Any ideas / comments wellcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is - have a look at Cedict - http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cedict

Comment: This is allmost everthing I want. However there are only complete words in this database, do you probably know of one that simply lists chinese characters one by one?

Comment: @flexy, you could simply loop through the dictionary and extract the entries that have only one simplified/traditional character.

Comment: sounds reasonable, but I doubt, that this would yield every character in simplified chinese, would it? I considered extracting them from the unicode character set, would you consider this a resonable approach?

Comment: @flexy, it will almost definitely yield every characters in simplified Chinese. The ones you might miss are some very rare/ancient/never used traditional characters. I've used the Cedict database for a Chinese dictionary application and it found it to be extremely detailed, it's rare to find anything missing from it :)

Comment: @this.lau_ is there one for Spanish that is similar to cedict?